# Fix java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present issue from NGINX

Tags: android, nginx

I use NGINX as a the web server for my load balancers. Recently the version we're using was updated from 1.12 to 1.14 and has started causing the below error in older versions of Android/Java applications I need to support.

`java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present`

I know this is an issue related to okhttp and looking through other SO questions, I can see that most people recommend updating the okhttp library in the mobile apps. In my case though this isn't an option. So my question is, is there a way I can fix this issue with out updating the Android app or downgrading the version of NGINX that my web servers are using?

Comment: Aha. Well, the best thing to do is to _make_ updating okhttp an option.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option. I'm curious if I just return a custom "status" header if that would fix. I can't seem to repro the issue in my testing environment even with all the same settings.